# Convert xml string from entity framework query to xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-xml

Consider the following:

```
public static XDocument GetMarkupXml( int baxId ) {
    using ( var context = new Sys.EntityModels.BfxEntities() ) {
        var markupXml = context.Baxes
            .Where( b => b.BaxId == baxId )
            .Select( b => b.BaxXml );

        return XDocument.Parse( markupXml );
    }
}
```

This is not compiling. It is erroring on "XDocument.Parse( markupXml )". Error message is: Unknown method 'Parse(System.Linq.IQueryable)' of 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument'

Im fairly new to EF, but I am sure my error is that my "markupXml" has not executed against the database and not retrieved the xml string I have stored there.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to execute the query. At the moment markupXml is an iqueryable .. not yet executed.

Change

```
var markupXml = context.Baxes
            .Where( b => b.BaxId == baxId )
            .Select( b => b.BaxXml );
```

To

```
var markupXml = context.Baxes
            .Where( b => b.BaxId == baxId )
            .Select( b => b.BaxXml ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Although markupXml may be null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a couple of things. Also, I am assuming that `BaxXml` is a string.

First thing is that your query is a `IQueryable<string>`, which means that it may contain more than one item. [`XDocument.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse.aspx) needs a `string` argument. Try using `First()` if that is logical.

```
string markupXml = context.Baxes
    .Where( b => b.BaxId == baxId )
    .First()
    .BaxXml;
```

Other options are `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, and `SingleOrDefault()`. If you use the "OrDefault" methods, make sure to check that the value is not null.

Second (from the error text), you are trying to perform c# function in sql. This might sound a bit odd, but take this code for example:

```
var someItems = context.Baxes.Select(x => b.BaxXml.ToString());
```

This would cause the same error you are getting, because sql does not know what to do with the `ToString()` method.

To fix this, use `ToList()` to force the query to pull data from the database before performing c# functions.